# Laravel passport ( can`t understand)

Tags: vue.js, axios, laravel-5.5, laravel-passport

I read a lot of articles and watched a lot of videos about Laravel passport but still can not understand some things.

I have an application which works with Laravel 5.5 + vueJs. All requests to the back-end are sent via axios. All my routes are located in api.php

```
Route::middleware('api')->group(function(){

    Route::get('/prepare/', 'CompgenApiController@prepareDefault');

    Route::post('/replace/', 'CompgenApiController@replaceImage');

    Route::get('/replaceall/', 'CompgenApiController@replaceAllImages');

    Route::get('/collage/', 'CompgenApiController@collage'); //@todo переделать на POST

    Route::get('/generate/', 'CompgenApiController@generate');

    Route::post('/upload/', 'CompgenApiController@userUpload');

    Route::post('/reupload/', 'CompgenApiController@moderationReupload');

});
```

Also I have a VK bot that sends requests to the same routes. 
At the moment I have some difficulties. For some routes, I need to check that the user is authorized (but this is an optional condition) and if it is true I need to write user id to the database. For me it was a surprise that

> Auth :: check

returned false though I was authorized. After some searches I learned that the session that starts after authorization is not connected with the API and I was recommended to use Passport. I can not understand the following things

1. Do I need to use a passport if requests are sent from my application from vueJs?
2. How to register users? Do I have to issue my token for each new user?
3. How can I verify that the user is authorized?
4. In some cases I need to check that the user is authorized but if it is not so then do not interfere with the request. How can I do that?

Maybe in my case I do not need a passport at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Passport is an oAuth2 server implementation, essentially, it allows you to authenticate users by passing a token with each request. If you do not want to authenticate a user, then you do not need to pass the token and passport doesn't get involved.

In terms of a `Laravel` app, if you are consuming your API from your own frontend, you probably just want to use the [implicit grant](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/passport#implicit-grant-tokens). Here's how you set that up:

1) Install passport and add it the `PassportServiceProvider` to config/app.php

2) `php artisan migrate` to setup the passport migrations

3) `php artisan passport:install` - to set up your oAuth server

4) In the `User` model add the `Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens` trait, like so:

```
namespace App;

use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, Notifiable;
    // Other model methods
}
```

5) Setup the passport routes by adding the following to the `boot` method of your `app\Providers\AuthServiceProviders.php`:

```
\Laravel\Passport\Passport::routes();
```

6) Change your `api driver` in `config/auth.php` to `token`:

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'passport',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],
```

That sets up passport, now all you need to do to allow your app to consume your api is to add the `CreateFreshApiToken` Middleware to `web` in `app/Http/Kernel.php`, which handles all the token logic:

```
'web' => [
    // ..Other middleware...
    \Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CreateFreshApiToken::class,
],
```

Now all you need to do to protect a route is to use the auth:api middleware on that route:

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/profile','Api\UsersController@edit');
```

That should all work fine, but you'll also want to register a new user. All you do is add the auth routes as normal to `web.php`:

```
Route::post('/login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
Route::post('/logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout');
Route::post('/register', 'Auth\RegisterController@register');
```

You can then simply maks a post request to those routes and `Laravel` will handle all the token stuff for you.

That handles api routes that require authentication, however, you also mentioned that you want to check if a user is authenticated, but not necessarily lock the route, to do that you can simply use:

```
Auth::guard('api')->user();
```

Which will get the authenticated user, so you could do something like:

```
public function getGreeting(){
  $user = Auth::guard('api')->user();

  if($user !== null) {
    return response()->json(["message" => "Hello {$user->name}"], 200);
  }

  return response()->json(["message" => "Hello Guest"], 200);
}
```

That's it. Hopefully, I've covered everything there.

Comment: Sir that middleware CreateFreshApiToken generates token every request. On mobile app how can I get authenticated accessing the api?

Comment: @Beginner You'll need to generate a token for your user then send that in the header of the request. You can find out more about that [in the protecting routes section of the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/passport#protecting-routes)

Comment: In laravel that middleware creates a token and use that token to make a request on api. On mobile app where/how can I get that token ? How can I generate that?

Comment: @Beginner that's in the doc's [Issuing Access Tokens section](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/passport#issuing-access-tokens), you'll probably want the [Password Grant](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/passport#password-grant-tokens)

Comment: last question sir i when's the time when I need to use this \Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CreateFreshApiToken::class, because im planning my api on laravel can be accessible on mobile app also but ofcourse with api auth.

Comment: Sorry for bumping this post sir. I've read a lot of example and tutorials your answer here helps me more to understand it.

Comment: The `CreateFreshApToken` is usually used when your Laravel frontend needs to talk to your Laravel API, this is usually used when creating an SPA and is simply a convenient way to avoid the whole oAuth flow, all your user does is login and laravel handles the rest. [Here's that section of the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/passport#consuming-your-api-with-javascript)

Comment: So the CreateFreshApiToken is not suitable for mobile app that wants to access the api on laravel?